# Does db computation worth Parallelizing?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, db2

I use DB2 9.7.5 64Bits. The server has enough memory but no clustering.

I need to make huge computations : compute several (roughly 20) ratios in my db. Some of them can take as long as 25 seconds.

The results are stored in a result table.

Now I have several solutions (As a policy, we exclude Stored Proc).

I call each ratio, one at a time from a java client OR 
I call several ratios in a multi threaded java client.

My assumption is that it is useless to call from a multi threaded since my db is the bottleneck. But I'm not wholly sure that the db engine really gives 100% of the cpu for 1 query. I think that the engine must probably be able to share its cpu power between several queries.

I am currently reading the IBM Data manual but would like to have your feedback.

Many thanks.

Comment: I doubt seriously that db engine can give 100% cpu. unless its multithreaded by nature, if not then you should make it so

Answer (score 0):

> I need to make huge computations : compute several (roughly 20) ratios in my db. Some of them can take as long as 25 seconds.

25 seconds is not necessarily a bad thing. maybe its a wonderful result, depends on what you compute

> Now I have several solutions (As a policy, we exclude Stored Proc).

Stored proc are not evil, you just need to know how to use them safely

> My assumption is that it is useless to call from a multi threaded since my db is the bottleneck. But I'm not wholly sure that the db engine really gives 100% of the cpu for 1 query. I think that the engine must probably be able to share its cpu power between several queries.

multithreading in java never hearts (as long as you keep the threads safe), especially useful in your case when you are doing alot of calculations. 
I don's use db2 so I don't know how good it is on multithreading, but if its single threaded I doubt that it will ever reach 100% cpu usage. you should check the conf files of your db2 to tweek it a little bit
Also read the article about [IBM DB2 clustering](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iisinfsv/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.productization.iisinfsv.ha.install.doc/topics/wsisinst_pln_ha_xmeta_db2cluster.html)

I also suggest using a [data warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) tool to analyze your script performance againest the db2

Good luck

Comment: Given that DB2 (pretty much all versions) was written to run on enterprise hardware (mainframes...) with at least _dozens_ of cores, it can deal with making things multi-threaded.  There are certain scenarios you have to watch out for, same as for Java, but the OP should probably be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Materialized Query Tables](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509melnyk/). If what you are working with is reporting, and especially doesn't require absolutely up-to-date information, you can set up MQTs that will contain the parts that are heavy to calculate with for instance hourly versions.